# How to implement notification concept in service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I have an application where i need to implement the concept of notification in service.

Is it possible to implement notification in Service? Currently when i included notification, it shows an error 'IllegalArgument Exception'

Thanks,

Niki

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a service that implements a Voice Launcher for an app. It performs continuous offline speech recognition while the screen is unlocked, and launches a certain app when it detects a keyphrase. This Voice Launcher consists of that service, a notification item with resume/start/stop buttons to control speech recognition, and broadcast receivers to detect screen status, and clicks on the notification's buttons. It has no graphical interface other than the notifications, so YES, it is possible. If you describe your problem more I can share the code.